# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown inside of text input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi I want to build form using Twitter Bootstrap with dropdown menu **inside** of text input. Like this ->[image]

I've managed only do it in this way

```
      <div class="input-append">
    <form method="get" action="/option" class="navbar-search" id="searchForm">
      <input type="text" size="16" placeholder="Search string" name="query">
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle searchMain" style="width: 150 px;"><span>Option 1</span> <b class="caret"></b></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="search-dropdown" style="left: 220px;">
        <li><a href="#" id="option-1">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="option-2">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="option-3">Option 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-white icon-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

But in this case droptdown is outside of text input. Is it possible to put dropdown inside of text input using Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: Broad question. Take a look at the 'position' attribute for CSS.

Comment: Can you rephrase your post to ask a specific question. As written, your post doesn't fit StackOverflow's question-and-answer format.

Comment: If I understand correctly @gv0zd wants to place a control INSIDE the textbox. Bootstrap allows you to append and prepend the control which essentialls attaches a control to the side of the textbox. In the example you can see `gv0zd` wants a control in this case a drop down inside the textbox that is inside the borders of the textbox. I created a solution here: http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2013/08/placing-text-and-controls-inside-text.html

Comment: Yes, INSIDE was a keyword for my question. But it was closed :( Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Forms section of the bootstrap docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Your markup will look something like this:

```
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedDropdownButton" type="text">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Action
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The key here is the `input-append` class.

Comment: it's not exactly what i want. I want to put button inside of text input, not to to group. But thank you for answer.